# Problem with iwlwifi on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I'm using HP Omen dc-0006nm notebook with Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it. After browsing web for some time, WiFi speed starts oscillating until eventually reaches 0 kbps. Sometimes it can take too long to even open a simple page.

I've tried to install iwlwifi driver again, but problem persists after every reboot. What could I to?

Comment: What encryption settings do you have at the router/AP? Only WPA2-AES should be used.

Comment: In security page it says WPA2.